# Java: How to create a sorted string ArrayList based on Custom object ArrayList without using Sort()

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a class called `Word` in which each instance has `String`, `ArrayList<Character>`, and a `double`. Let's say there are 3 instances of this class. I would like to create a new `ArrayList<String>` in which all 3 word strings are contained. However, the order of the Strings must go from high to low of the doubles from their original instances.  The major stipulation of this project is that the `Collections.sort` method cannot be used. Please see the code below and let me know if you can think of a way to write this loop (a loop is needed because there is actually +50,000 words):

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class WordRecommender {

    String fileName;

    public WordRecommender(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Word> objectArray = new ArrayList<Word>();

    objectArray.add(new Word("people", null ,0.8));
    objectArray.add(new Word("dogs", null ,0.4));
    objectArray.add(new Word("cats", null ,0.6));

    ArrayList<String> outputArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < finalArray.size(); i++) {
      // code here to find the value of each double and place the 
      // associated strings into output Array from highest to lowest
    }

    // ideal outputArray order = ["people", "cats", "dogs"]

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Word {

    String wordName;
    ArrayList<Character> uniqueLetters;
    double percent;

    public Word(String string, double percent) {
        ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) { 
            tempArray.add(string.charAt(i));
        }

        this.wordName = string;
        this.uniqueLetters = tempArray;
        this.percent = percent;
    }

}
```

Comment: look into the Comparable interface, and the compareTo method. That will help you compare objects, without the sort method being used.

Comment: It is not an easy task to implement a sorting algorithm with a single loop maybe not possible. You should use at least a recursion. If the requirement is not to use any built-in sort method then you should have a look common sorting algorithms like Bubble Sort, Quick Sort, Merge Sort and so on. Bubble sort is the most primitive one if you need to consider performance then I think you should go with either Quick or Merge sort. Just let me know if you still need to a sample, I can post you an implementation with one of the algorithms I mentioned above. Cheers

Comment: @beastlyCoder thank you for helping to send me in the right direction.  Looking into these now

Comment: @YavuzTas thank you for the reply!  An example will be very helpful if you have the time.  Which of those three methods do you recommend (I do not care about performance for this item)?

Comment: @beastlyCoder your advice is good in order to isolate compare logic so that you can keep it more modifiable. But still, he needs to apply a sorting algorithm even if it's the bubble sort as I guess.

Comment: yeah i understanding, just offering maybe a different approach

Comment: If the stipulation is that you cannot use `Collections.sort`, then you can use a sorted data structure like a `TreeSet` to order the elements, then use it to populate your array.

Comment: @Josh - I think your proposal is much better and practical if there is not any restriction against using built-in collections. Why don't you post an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you need to achieve can be broken in 2 major steps:

1. Describing how, giving 2 `Word`s, which of them will be put before the other in the `List`
2. Using the comparing method to actually sort your list of `Word`s.

## Step 1:  How can we decide which word comes first?

Java has an interface called `Comparable`. The name is pretty self-explanatory. When you implement this interface in your `Word` class, you are telling Java that instances of this class can be compared against each other.

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word>{
```

When you edit this line in your `Word` class, your IDE will probably complain about a "missing `compareTo()` method". The `compareTo()` method is defined in the `Comparable` interface and its job is deciding, from 2 instances, which one should be considered "larger" (or in our case, should be put first in the `List`).

An example of a usage is: `"apple".compareTo("banana");`. This method call should return a positive number if the first instance ("apple") is "larger", a negative number if the second instance ("banana") is "larger", or zero if both are of the same "value". By the way, the `compareTo()` method implemented by `String`s in Java evaluates instances by alphabetical order.

So let's implement our version of the `compareTo()` method for our `Word` class.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Word anotherWord) {
    if(this.percent > anotherWord.percent) {
        return 1;
    } else if (this.percent < anotherWord.percent) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this implementation returns a positive value if the first instance is greater than the second, and a negative value in the other way around.

Now that we have a way of comparing our `Words`, we can move on to the sorting part.

## Step 2: Sorting algorithms

There are a huge variety of sorting algorithms available on the internet. Some are less efficient, some are easier to implement. You can research some of them [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/#algo).

For me, the easiest sorting algorithm is called [BubbleSort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/). It is not very efficient, though.

```
ArrayList<Word> objectArray = new ArrayList<Word>();

objectArray.add(new Word("people", 0.8));
objectArray.add(new Word("dogs", 0.4));
objectArray.add(new Word("cats", 0.6));

for(int i = 0; i < objectArray.size() - 1; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < objectArray.size() - i - 1; j++) {
        // Remember: a compareTo() call returning a negative number
        // means that the first instance is smaller than the second.
        if(objectArray.get(j).compareTo(objectArray.get(j + 1)) < 0) {
            Word auxiliary = objectArray.get(j);
            objectArray.set(j, objectArray.get(j + 1));
            objectArray.set(j + 1, auxiliary);
        }
    }
}
```

These two nested `for` loops will sort `objectArray` in descending order of `percent`.

Comment: wow thank you so much for this!  I'm trying out your code right now and the only bug is under the method ```compareTo```.  The error message is ```The method compareTo (Word) is undefined for the type Word```.  Should I alter this line so that it specifically looking at the ```percent``` element of Word?

Comment: This error message means that the compiler didn't find a method with the signature `compareTo(word)` inside the class `Word`. Did you put it in the right place? Also, be sure that the parameter passed to that method is a `Word`, not an `Object` type.

Comment: yes, you are correct, I had the method in the wrong class!   Thank you so much for all the help.  I will test the solution now

Comment: Hey @MateusBandeira, really great answer for covering basics, I love it. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Thanks @YavuzTas. Finally felt confident enough to write answers and give back to the community that helped me so much for so many years.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a solution that involves a sorting algorithm and usage of `java.util.Comparable` both.

First, you need to implement `Word` class with `java.util.Comparable` so that you can define how to compare `Word` class in order to determine which one is greater or lower than the other. In this case, it will be the `percent` field.

```java
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {

    String wordName;
    ArrayList<Character> uniqueLetters;
    double percent;

    public Word(String string, double percent) {
        ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            tempArray.add(string.charAt(i));
        }

        this.wordName = string;
        this.uniqueLetters = tempArray;
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Word o) {
        // It is better to delegate to built-in Double compare 
        // because all we need to compare doubles
        return Double.compare(this.percent, o.percent);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.wordName;
    }

}
```

Second, the most important part is to implement a sorting algorithm. It can be challenging to implement them on your own so I suggest [study them](https://www.baeldung.com/java-quicksort) first.

For my solution it will be a regular implementation of Quick Sort algorithm as follows:

```java
public class QuickSort {

    private Word[] array;

    public QuickSort(Word... words) {
        this.array = words;
    }

    public Word[] sort(){
        this.sort(this.array, 0, this.array.length-1);
        return this.array;
    }

    private void sort(Word[] array, int begin, int end) {

        //exit condition
        if (begin >= end)
            return;

        Word pivot = array[end];
        int sortIndex = begin;

        for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
            // instead of > we use compareTo to externalize comparison logic 
            // greater than (>) means we sort in descending order  
            if (array[i].compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
                Word swap = array[sortIndex];
                array[sortIndex] = array[i];
                array[i] = swap;
                sortIndex++;
            }
        }
        //placing pivot to the sort index
        Word swap = array[sortIndex];
        array[sortIndex] = pivot;
        array[end] = swap;

        this.sort(array, begin, sortIndex-1);
        this.sort(array, sortIndex+1, end);

    }

}
```

Finally, you just use `QuickSort` helper class to sort your collection of `Word` and get the sorted output:

```java
public class WordRecommender {

    String fileName;

    public WordRecommender(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Word> objectArray = new ArrayList<Word>();

        objectArray.add(new Word("people" ,0.8));
        objectArray.add(new Word("dogs", 0.4));
        objectArray.add(new Word("cats" ,0.6));

        QuickSort quickSort = new QuickSort(objectArray.toArray(new Word[]{}));
        Word[] sortedWordArray = quickSort.sort();

        //output: [people, cats, dogs]
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(sortedWordArray));

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to write this!  I am looking into implementing your solution now

Comment: You're welcome. MateusBandeira's answer is great for covering basics. Also, you should consider Josh's proposal which is written in the comments. It is probably the most practical one. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome thank you so much again!  This is a huge help